# MSSQL Trigger - Issue

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I have a SQL trigger on a table, which will fire after insert, update and delete.

I insert all the affected records in a separate physical table with codes defining the state of update. Following code snippet is the trigger defined.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[DATA_CACHE]
   ON  [dbo].[DATA_USAGE] 
for Insert,Update,Delete
AS 
BEGIN
    if(select COUNT(*) from inserted)>0
    begin
        if (select COUNT(*) from deleted)>0
        BEGIN
            --update
            INSERT INTO CACHE_UPDATE_TABLE (CODE, ID, DATE, COUNT)
            SELECT 2, ins.ID, ins.DATE, ins.COUNT
            from inserted ins
        END
        else
        begin
            -- insert
            INSERT INTO  CACHE_UPDATE_TABLE (CODE, ID, DATE, COUNT)
            SELECT 1, ins.ID, ins.DATE, ins.COUNT
            from inserted ins
        end
    END
    else 
    BEGIN
        -- delete
        INSERT INTO  CACHE_UPDATE_TABLE (CODE, ID, DATE, COUNT)
        SELECT 3, del.ID, del.DATE, del.COUNT
        from deleted del
    end
END
SELECT * FROM CACHE_UPDATE_TABLE
```

As you can see in the above trigger i had added an additional statement after the trigger by MISTAKE, selecting all values from the target table. This statement was after the defined trigger, however when i tried to alter the trigger, by right clicking on trigger and selecting modify, it also showed me the select statement after the end block of trigger.

Does this mean, every time the trigger is fired this select statement executes ? this is my first question (Question A) - May be a silly one, but i am a little confused about this.

My second question is (Question B) I encounter locking issue on the CACHE_UPDATE_TABLE, could this be the reason for locking? Also there is a SQL job which runs every one minute to check the CACHE_UPDATE_TABLE table, and then i perform some operation(linked server related) and delete these records from CACHE_UPDATE_TABLE after i am done. Locking Issue could be because of this?? and if so, how do i counter it?

My third question is (Question C) Is this the best way to do this operation using triggers or can i do it some other way? Is the trigger defined proper?

-Any help will be appreciated... Thanks.

Comment: You've got a lot of questions in there which is why you haven't received any answers. I, for example, can partially answer A and fully answer C, but not B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a lot of different questions in there which is probably why you've not received any answers, but I'll cover what I can.

A) That's quite an interesting question actually. I would have assumed that it would do nothing - It'd be executed when you create the trigger but then wouldn't be part of the trigger - however I've noticed odd behaviour with this before so I tested with a simple stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.test ( @i INT ) AS
BEGIN
    SELECT @i  
END;
SELECT 'hi'
GO
```

Executing the stored procedure causes the `SELECT 'hi'` to fire as well as the `SELECT @i`. I still don't have an answer for your question, but I would definitely make sure not to have any stray SQL outside the trigger when you create it for this reason alone.

I've just investigated this a little more and apparently the end of the stored procedure is wherever the first `GO` is after the procedure (which SQL Server automatically adds to the end if you don't use one). So you could define your whole procedure after the `END` - you can still use the parameters too.

This seems to be because the `BEGIN` and `END` aren't a required part of the stored procedure definition - they're not actually indicating the begin and end of the stored procedure, they're just an unrelated `BEGIN...END` block like you might put after and `IF` statement. You can have as many `BEGIN...END` blocks as you like in the procedure definition, or none at all.

C) I would definitely change your trigger. You've massively complicated it by combining the 3 triggers without reusing any code. The only reason to combine `INSERT`,`UPDATE` and `DELETE` triggers is so that you don't have to duplicate code. You should either:

- Have 3 separate triggers, each containing only the relevant `INSERT` - that way you remove all of the conditional logic.
- Keep them together but work out only the `CODE` using some conditional logic and have only 1 `INSERT` statement.

I'd be tempted to go with the 3 separate triggers, or at least an separate out the delete trigger, and then use `CASE del.ID IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 2 END` for the `CODE` on the `INSERT`/`UPDATE` trigger. But you could combine them with (untested):

```
INSERT INTO  CACHE_UPDATE_TABLE (CODE, ID, DATE, COUNT)
SELECT CASE WHEN del.ID IS NULL THEN 1
            WHEN ins.ID IS NULL THEN 3
            ELSE 2 END
    ,ISNULL(ins.ID, del.ID)
    ,ISNULL(ins.DATE, del.DATE)
    ,ISNULL(ins.COUNT, del.COUNT)
FROM deleted del
FULL OUTER JOIN inserted ins ON del.ID = ins.ID
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Having a join in the trigger still seem to be expensive. In my trigger i just have two conditions which will be checked every time and the insert will go through. I dont think that will be expensive as far as performance is concerned. I may be wrong, i will test it out.

But yeah pretty strange the way your procedure reacted, after the END statement whatever you add, it seems to be executed anyways.

Comment: Neither will be expensive in these circumstances, but `IF` statements prevent good query plans from being cached, so I'd bet big money that the `JOIN` will perform better - only way to know would be to benchmark though. The best performance would undoubtedly be from 3 separate triggers that would all have ideal execution plans cached.

Comment: Edited my answer with a little more information on A

Answer (score 0):

Just remove that

```
SELECT * FROM CACHE_UPDATE_TABLE
```

Comment: Dude, i already removed it... I wanted to know why it is getting executed when its outside the trigger.